# Aspect ratio of image within a figure

Tags: html, css

I have a figure with a caption, like this:

```
<figure>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I also have `img{max-width:100%}` in my CSS.

I want to set both the width and height of the image, and preserve its aspect ratio when the width is reduced by the max-width below its set value. So, I tried this:

```
<figure>
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200" style="object-fit:contain"/>
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is roughly what I want, but, when the image is 'letterboxed', the caption ends up a long way from the bottom of the image.

Is there a way to get the result I want, while keeping the caption immediately below the bottom of the image?

Comment: Hey @twsh—when I saw you chose J_BB's answer, out of curiosity, I put their solution in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/cutlersheridan/pen/dywydMo) to test it, and there's still a large gap between the image and "Caption," plus the image is wider than the 100px you specified using `width="100"` and taller than your `height="200"`. Did it work in your project? Because my answer takes a lot less code and, as you can see in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cutlersheridan/pen/QWzWQEm), does work, but I would love to know if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @Cutler.Sheridan I think that I was confused about several things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `object-fit: contain`, the image's original aspect ratio is already being retained because the entire image has to fit within its parent.  So if the image is originally 100px wide and 150px tall and you have your image set to `width: 100px` and `height: 200px`, the image's height will still be 150px, but an extra 25px of space will be added to the top and bottom of the `figure` element.

To fix this, all you have to do is set height to "auto."

```css
img {
  /* moving your style declarations here for readability */
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Now, if you're actually trying to define the width and height and force the image to conform to that, you should be using something other than `object-fit: contain`.  You can read about your other options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), but maybe you're trying to set the width/height of the `figure` element and have the image fill that space.  In that case, you could do something like this:

```css
figure {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that addresses the gap between the caption and the bottom of the image.

Comment: @twsh Well, those extra 50px of space I mentioned in my first paragraph create the gap you're trying to get rid of, so when the height is set to "auto," the gap doesn't exist as the height will always set itself according to the aspect ratio with your defined width.  Or if you're asking about my second solution, there is also no gap there because the image is set to fill the defined space, so the caption will be immediately under it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the aspect ratio to stay the same no matter what image is loaded (i.e.: if the image comes back from an API and are unpredictable), you can use the [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) css attribute achieve your desired result of maintaining the aspect ratio of the image while also keeping the caption immediately below the bottom of the image.

HTML:

```html
<figure class="image-figure">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200" />
  </div>
  <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```css
.image-figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2; /* Width / Height ratio */
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Explanation:

1. The `image-figure` class is applied to the `figure` element to set up a flex container with a column layout for proper alignment.
2. The `image-container` div contains the image and is assigned an aspect ratio of 1:2 (width:height) to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.
3. The `max-width: 100%;` on the `image-container` ensures that the image doesn't exceed its container's width.
4. The `img` styles ensure that the image scales down to fit within its container while preserving its aspect ratio and using `object-fit: contain`.
5. The caption remains immediately below the image due to the flex column layout.

This approach combines the `aspect-ratio` CSS attribute with flex layout to achieve your desired result. The caption will stay positioned below the bottom of the image even when it's letterboxed.

Comment: Hey J_BB—I'm not sure this works.  I had never used CSS's aspect-ratio attribute before, so, out of curiosity, I put your solution in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/cutlersheridan/pen/dywydMo) and there's a large gap between the image and "Caption."  Am I doing something wrong?  Additionally is there any benefit to your answer over [the answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76916413/13273704)?  Because mine takes a lot less code and, as you can see in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cutlersheridan/pen/QWzWQEm), *does* work, but I would love to know if there's something I'm missing.